# print lines that don't match array elements

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

I have an array

```
arr=( 'error one' 'error two' 'error three' )
```

and a file I want to find errors in

```
a.txt
```

with contents (example).

```
error one
error two
error three
error four
error five
error six
error seven
eight
nine
ten
```

When I run my script I want to ignore all errors I have already found (the errors in the array) and find new ones.

So far I have this

```
arr=( 'error one' 'error two' 'error three' )
grep -v 'error one\|error two\|error three' a.txt | grep error
```

which returns this (correct).

```
error four
error five
error six
error seven
```

The contents of the array will change over time though, based on more errors I find, or errors I stop finding, and I would prefer to instead reference the array as a whole rather than list each item.

So far I have something like this.

```
arr=( 'error one' 'error two' 'error three' )
function join_by { local d=$1; shift; echo -n "$1"; shift; printf "%s" "${@/#/$d}"; }
list=$(join_by "\|" "${arr[@]}")
echo ${list}
grep -v ${list} a.txt | grep error
```

Of course this doesn't work, but I don't know how to proceed from here, or whether to change the method entirely.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to join patterns by `\|`, grep accepts a newline separated list as well. So you can simply do:

```
grep -v "$(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}")" a.txt | grep error
```

Proof of concept:

```
$ arr=(2 4)
$ seq 4 | grep -v "$(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}")"
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` can read patterns from a file with `-f`, one per line, and you can make the array elements show one per line with `printf`:

```
grep -v -f <(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}") a.txt | grep error
```

Comment: **If** the array should have a lot of elements, then I would reverse the command to remove the unnecessary lines first: `grep error a.txt | grep -v -f <(printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}")`